# How to get the results out to load the values in nested lists without using foreach loop?

Tags: c#

Am trying to understand if there is any better way to load the below results into nested lists without using a `foreach` loop?

```
class Lead
{
    public int Empid { get; set; }
    public int EmpName { get; set; }
    public int EmpCategory { get; set; }
    List<Lead> TeamMembers { get; set; }
}
```

I have a collection like the one below. The least sequence will always be Team lead and the same number in EmpCategory field will be team members. How to load the Team lead and team members as defined in the above structure.

```
   EmpID  EmpName  EmpCategory  Sequence
    1        A         12          1
    2        B         14          2
    3        C         15          3
    4        D         16          4
    5        E         12          5
    6        F         12          6
    7        G         12          7
```

Comment: Its not very clear what you are after. I assume the nested list is `TeamMembers` but I'm not sure I understand what you expect to go in there...

Comment: List<Lead> will have 

1  A  12 1

List<TeamMembers> Will have 

5   E  12
6   F   12
7   G   12

Comment: How does that logic work? Why are EmpID 5, 6 and 7 in the team of EmpId 1? Also you say you are looking for a better way - you should include whatever way you currently have so we can tell you if there are any problems or optimisations. That would also help to understand the logic of what you are doing.